# Get Color Picker value in tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags, color-picker

I'm creating a text editor and so far everything is great, except for a little mess I don't know how to fix.

I need to get the value of the color selected by the user into the tag that is inserted into the textarea.

I don't reeally know how to use JSFiddle, but I think I can share it: https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/mh9rfwct/

```
<script>//Color picker

//color picker

var theInput = document.getElementById("colorChoice");
var theColor = theInput.value;
theInput.addEventListener("input", function() {

document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = theInput.value;
}, false);

//Tags

function btnEditor(h, a, i) { // helloacm.com
    var g = document.getElementById(h);
    g.focus();
    if (g.setSelectionRange) {
        var c = g.scrollTop;
        var e = g.selectionStart;
        var f = g.selectionEnd;
        g.value = g.value.substring(0, g.selectionStart) + a + g.value.substring(g.selectionStart, g.selectionEnd) + i + g.value.substring(g.selectionEnd, g.value.length);
        g.selectionStart = e;
        g.selectionEnd = f + a.length + i.length;
        g.scrollTop = c;
    } else {
        if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            g.focus();
            var b = document.selection.createRange();
            if (b.text != "") {
                b.text = a + b.text + i;
            } else {
                b.text = a + "REPLACE" + i;
            }
            g.focus();
        }
    }// helloacm.com
}

</script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="fonts-box fonts-color" style="text-align: center;">
            <form>
                <input type="color" value="" id="colorChoice">
            </form> 
            <p id="hex" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></p>
            <button id="colorSelect" onclick="btnEditor('ECEditor', '[color=#VALUEHERE]', '[/color]');">Select</button>
</div>
<textarea id="ECEditor" class="editor-textarea" name="editor-text"></textarea>
```

Comment: You are looking to make the text fields, text color be set by the chosen color int he input on click yes? So when the user types in the text field the color they choose will be used for the text?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to let the user chose the color of the text, but only the part of the text he/she selects, not the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function btnEditor() { 

var but = document.getElementById('wrapper')
var color = document.getElementById('colorChoice').value
console.log(color)

but.innerHTML = '<button id=\"colorSelect\" onclick=\"btnEditor(\'ECEditor\', \'[color=' + color + ']\',\'[/color]\');">Select</button>'
   
}

/*
this answer
<button id="colorSelect" onclick="btnEditor('ECEditor', '[color=#000000]','[/color]');">Select</button>

your request
<button id="colorSelect" onclick="btnEditor('ECEditor','[color=#VALUEHERE]','[/color]');">Select</button>
*/
```

```html
<div class="fonts-box fonts-color" style="text-align: center;">
            <form>
                <input type="color" value="" id="colorChoice">
            </form> 
            <p id="hex" style="padding-bottom: 3px;"></p>
            <span id = 'wrapper'>
            <button id="colorSelect" onclick="btnEditor();">Select</button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but that way the color wouldn't be in the tag [color=#colorcodehere]text[/color], where I need to place it. :(

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not what I'm trying to do. I need is for the color code to be placed inside the [color=] tag, the one place in the textarea where the user selects part of a text. :(

Comment: well you just need to modify the innerHTML.  I've updated it again to show you how.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: try this now, I was missing a '

Comment: just to be clear, you want to add the color chosen to the button tag? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the color chosen to the [color=] tag, so it would be like [color=#000000].

Comment: Like in this example is only missing the code in the tag, while the tags are placed properly around the selected text a user writes: https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/mh9rfwct/

Comment: what's wrong with provided solution?  It adds the color to the button tag

Comment: Oh, now it worked! Thank you very much! <3 What it was missing was the (h, a i) in the function parentheses for the rest of the code to work, because without it the text wasn't showing in the textarea. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
const getCurrentColorPicker = () => {
  return document.getElementById("colorChoice").value;
};

function btnEditor(h, a, i) {
  console.log(getCurrentColorPicker());
  // helloacm.com

  var editor = document.getElementById(h);

  editor.value = a + getCurrentColorPicker() + i;

  // other code...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. The code does not place the color code inside the tag but out of it, and replace the text inside the textarea instead of wrapping it as it is right now. :(

Comment: I changed my answer. The problem was solved?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but still doesn't work as it should. :( This is how is going:  https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/tp6a4xqm/7/

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know exactly what you want. But I still made changes to the code. Follow this link. https://jsfiddle.net/7vmjngef/2/